Are Totally Different Python Scripts Running on the Same Host Influenced by the GIL?
As the question says, if I run two different python scripts on two different terminals (Ubuntu 22.04) like
$ python3 script1.py

$ python3 script2.py

does the global interpreter lock still prevent their concurrent execution? Or does the GIL only prevents thread pooling or process pooling (via the concurrent.futures module) only within the same parent process?

The GIL only affects threads running within a single process.  Two processes will each get their own GIL and they won't interfere.

No. Similarly, if you use Python’s multiprocessing(rather than multi-threading), each process has its own GIL.

The point of the GIL is that all the threads share the same memory, and it needs to be synchronized. Why would totally independent python processes need to share the GIL?
